# Script to acquire quote of the day from previous posts?

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr, getelementsbytagname

I have spent the last 4 hours trying to write a script for a "Quote of the day" display on my tumblr blog. I am a beginner at javascript. So can you please help me with the javascript and tell me what I need to change to make it work? Also How will I be able to format the text that the script produces to look like the ?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var now = new Date();
    var todayAtMidn = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
    var quoteTag = getElementsByTagName("div")
    for (var i = 3; i < quoteTag.length; i++)`
    var quoteDate = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 3; i < quoteDate.length; i++) {
        if ((quoteDate[i].getAttribute("class") == "date") && (quoteTag[i].getAttribute("class") == "tag")) {
            if ((todayAtMidn.getTime() == quoteDate.getTime()) && (quoteTag == 'QOT')) {
                document.write("Quote Of the Day:{Quote}")
            } else {
                document.write('Thank God, its a new day!');
            }
        } else {
            document.write('Thank God, its a new day!')
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I was trying to do was, get the content/text from one of my normal quote posts, provided that the quote post has the tag "QOT" and was posted on the current date (so today). Then the text/ content will be displayed as "quote of the day" on special section of the website.

heres my website: teamnigeria.tumblr.com

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets start with:

1. Initially

   ```
   (function () {

   var post=null;
   ```
2. loop over the posts on the current page:

   ```
   var posts=getPosts();
   var midnight_today=getMidnight();

   for(var i=0, l=posts.length; i<l; i++) {
   ```
3. stop when we find the first post with the tag `QOT` and that was posted today

   ```
      var post_time = getPostTime(post[i]);
      if (postHasTag(posts[i], 'QOT') && post_time > midnight_today) {
          post = posts[i];
          break;
      }

   }
   ```
4. if we don't find a post: set quote to "No quote picked for today"

   ```
   if (post === null) { 
       setQuote("No quote picked for today");
   } else {
   ```
5. otherwise: set the quote to the text of the post we found

   ```
       setQuote(getQuoteFromPost(post));
   }

   })();
   ```

If all the undefined functions were defined, this would do what you ask.

---

As all the posts on a tumblr page have the class `post` and the quote posts have the class `quote` so given jQuery:

```
(function () {
  var quotes = $("div.post.quote");
  if (quotes.length > 0) {
    $('div#header > h8').empty().append(
      quotes.first().find("div.content > blockquote").clone()
    );
  }
})();
```

replaces the daily quote with the first quote on the page, and if there isn't one the contents of `div#header > h8` remain as the placeholder content. If this was also going to check the date, it would need to parse the contents of `div.post.quote > div.date` and compare the date.

Comment: Thank you, so which are the undefined? and I don't see how this helps me get the post date, or the text/content of the post itself?

Comment: How each of those functions is defined depends on the structure of the page. What I wanted to give you was an idea of the proper control flow.

Comment: Oh Ok, well its a tumblr page, but because there are so many types of posts, I have to somehow define the class...